# Connect to hotstar via GCP Virtual Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, streaming

I am currently outside India and want to access Hotstar. I spinned up new GCP VM in India/Delhi Region, attached it with external IP address. Still streaming apps such as Hotstar/Sony Liv detect it as VPN/Proxy Server.
Shouldn't it pass geo restrictions now?

I am connecting to GCP VM via Chrome Remote Desktop from my local machine.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Some geolocation services use the registered address of Google for Google IP addresses. That address is in California. Also, any Google IP address would not be a residential or small business IP address by geolocation detection logic.

Comment: Some streaming service providers are blocking all data center IP address ranges. You can visit https://www.ip2location.com and see if one IP address originating from data center.

Comment: So is it possible to assign a residential IP to GCP VM?

Comment: That is called [BYOIP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/bring-your-own-ip). You must own that address.